# Graph-Tool KCore functionality

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph-tool

I'm digging into [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de) and I try to build a graph, which shows me the current in and out degrees of my vertices. I checked out the [sample](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/topology.html?highlight=kcore_decomposition#graph_tool.topology.kcore_decomposition) from the website, which works fine for me, but as I try to build my own random graph all the vertices show only "1" as vertex text, instead of the real number.

My current code looks like this:

```
g = Graph()
g.set_directed(False)
N = 50

v = g.add_vertex()
vlist = [v]

for i in range(1, N):
  v = g.add_vertex()

  i = randint(0, len(vlist))
  target = vlist[i]

  e = g.add_edge(v, target)

  vlist.append(v)
  vlist.append(target)

graph_draw(g, output_size=[1000, 1000])
```

With the following result:
[image]

All good so far, but as I calculate the kcore via ...

```
kcore = kcore_decomposition(g)
```

... and draw the graph like ...

```
graph_draw(g, output_size=[1000, 1000], vertex_fill_color=kcore, 
       vertex_text=kcore)
```

.. the result is the following:

[image]

Which is really not the right result. If I check for the largest component with the following code:

```
largest = label_largest_component(g)
print(largest.a)
```

I will get an list with exact 50 times 1. 
Do I miss here something?

I reduced the size of the images, only to upload it here with a smaller size than 2MB. So that's why the current size is not 1000x1000 like as mentioned in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The result you get is in fact correct. Your graph is a tree, so all nodes belong to the 1-core. It is also connected, so there is only one component.